# Can I use, Blue Prism MS Excel VBO if I need to EXTRACT and SAVE "error message", "sold to party" and "contract" in an current excel format like this?

Tags: blueprism

Error Message -> xxx qty:          5.000    order qty:          6.000

Sales : xxxx     Sold to Party: 000xxxxxx      Customer: 000xxxxxxx

Contract : 0000xxxxxx  category: XX     date: xxxxxx

Comment: Yes…? It’d be quite trivial. Have you tried to build this…?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if these values are written into an excel in some capacity you can integrate with them as mentioned.